# AWK: Move information from several rows in columns

Tags: awk

actually I'm anewbie in awk. I just used it from time to time.
Now I have a problem that I try to solve in awk.

I have several xlsx files that I merge over csv into a txt using awk.

Files are like this:
ID - User - Group-ID - Group

Each ID can have more than one up to 4 lines, depending on how many groups the user is working on.

e.g.

- ID - User - Group-ID - Group
- 01 - AB - Group_11 - CDE
- 01 - AB - Group_12 - FGH
- 01 - AB - Group_13 - KLM
- 01 - AB - Group_14 - OPQ
- 02 - JI - Group_11 - CDE
- 02 - JI - Group_12 - ''
- 02 - JI - Group_13 - ''
- 02 - JI  - Group_14 - RFG

My wish is to switch the "Group-ID" in columns with the "Group" in their rows:

- ID - User - Group_11 - Group_12 - Group_13 - Group_14
- 01 - AB - CDE - FGH - KLM - OPQ
- 02 - JI - CDE - '' - '' - RFG

==> The '' are empty values. They can be "n.A." as well.

I realised it in MS Access using several queries, and merging them together. But it has to work with 2 million IDs ==> Currently up to 8 million rows.

I hope somebody can help me.

Regards,
David

Edit: edited "Input" to fit to the Output.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? There are many questions about joining files in Awk and reordering fields, including joining fields with the same primary key on the same output line -- find those and combine the answers you feel are suitable for you.

Comment: the input is missing the entries you have in your output.  Making it consistent will get your more non-guesswork solutions.

Comment: sorry you're right. I edited my question with completing the Input. I tried several snippets from my google searching. but they were not practical at all. I don't want to have all results of an ID in one Row, I want to move the rows (Group_ID) in columns and then for each ID I want to have the Group_ID information in their rows.